# Booting fault on Thnkpad T495 Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

When I switch on My Thinkpad T495 Ubuntu 20.04 it displays the Lenovo screen and then displays the Ubuntu screen with the spinning circle. When it boots it displays the login screen, however sometime the screen will go black with a cursor flashing top left. The only thing I can do is power off and reboot the thinkpad.

I tried updating my Bios and changing the settings from legacy to UEFI and adjusting the boot priority list. This did not solve the booting problem.

I tried changing the GRUB setting by changing "Splash Screen" to "quiet splash" and also "no Splash" but the problem still remains. If anyone can help I would be so grateful, Many Thanks from Paul

Comment: Many Lenovo models have needed UEFI update. Check your version. What video chip do you have? If nVidia, you may need "nomodeset". I permanently replace quiet splash with noplymouth, you then see boot process (and maybe where it stops if issue) and it is a bit faster.

Comment: Thank you for the help, the graphics chip is a Ryzen Vega. I will do the UEFI update as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "Advanced Options" in the GRUB menu and open Ubuntu in an old kernel. This should work.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out. Paul

Answer (score 0):

I installed the latest Ubuntu release 20.10 with the latest Kernel 5.8. The previous release was Ubuntu 20.04 with Kernel 5.4 and I was getting a boot failure occasionally hanging on the Black Ubuntu screen. 20.10 has made a massive difference and boots straight into Ubuntu login screen every time. Many thanks for your answers, Paul